# Texture drawn at wrong coordinates?

Tags: c++, sdl

I tried drawing a '1' texture at mouse coordinates when I press the 1 key:

```
switch (e.type)
{
    case SDL_QUIT:
    {
        quit = true;
        break;
    }
    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
    {
        switch (e.key.keysym.sym)
        {
            case SDLK_1:
            {
                SDL_Rect rect = {e.motion.x - 8, e.motion.y - 8, 16, 16};
                SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, gT[3], NULL, &rect);
                printf("1\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

I cannot comprehend why this doesn't work.

`gT[3]` is the texture of the '1'.

I thought maybe it is because its `e.key.keysym.sym` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SDL_Event::motion`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.24.2/include/SDL_events.h#L631) is only valid when [`SDL_Event::type`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.24.2/include/SDL_events.h#L623) is [`SDL_MOUSEMOTION`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.24.2/include/SDL_events.h#L108).

Stop trying to use `SDL_Event::motion` when `SDL_Event::type` is [`SDL_KEYDOWN`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.24.2/include/SDL_events.h#L98), perhaps by recording the X and Y coordinates of the most recent `SDL_MOUSEMOTION` event and using those instead.